# Taking two lines of input being time and the duration that's passed, displaying the new time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a program which takes two inputs. The first one takes the time of the day (in 24 hour system) such as 12:30 or 14:00 and the second input is the duration of time that's passed (in minutes) such as 30 or 90 (thus showing 1:00 or 15:30)

My main issue is I am having a lot of if/else statements and I'm thinking I may be doing this very inefficiently. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out all the special cases I need to account for. The program currently works if you give it numbers that don't make the hour change twice. I could really use some help on making this more efficient. I commented as much as I can in my code to help you understand my intentions with each line of code.

**Code:**

```
# Taking User Input
startTime = input()
duration = int(input())

# Splitting up the hour and minutes by the colon
rawTime = startTime.split(':')

# Assigning the hour and the minute variables
hourHand = int(rawTime[0])
minuteHand = int(rawTime[1])

# Giving the remainder when you add the minutes and the duration (so 
# if it goes over 60 you know by how much) 
newMinuteHand = (minuteHand+duration)%60

# Checking to see if newMinuteHand is greater than 0, meaning it goes 
# into the next hour.
# Also checking to make sure the hour is not 23:00 or close to 
# midnight because that carries over
# to 0:00
if newMinuteHand >= 0 and hourHand != 23:
   newHourHand = hourHand + 1
   # A couple statements needed here to correctly format the minute 
   # side.
    if newMinuteHand >= 10:
    newTime = str(newHourHand) + ':' + str(newMinuteHand) 
    print(newTime)
   else:
      newTime = str(newHourHand) + ':0' + str(newMinuteHand)
      print(newTime)

# Checking for the case that the hour is 23:00
elif newMinuteHand >= 0 and hourHand == 23:
   newHourHand = 0

   if newMinuteHand >= 10:
    newTime = str(newHourHand) + '0:' + str(newMinuteHand) 
    print(newTime)
   else:
      newTime = str(newHourHand) + '0:0' + str(newMinuteHand)
      print(newTime)
```

Comment: Take a look at the `datetime` module (it's part of the standard library).  It has  `time` and `timedelta` classes that handle all of the time math for you.

Comment: Brad is right datetime would be best in a professional setting.  As any programmer has probably learned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to something like this:

```
hourHand = 23
minuteHand = 00
duration = 61

total_minutes = minuteHand + duration
additional_hours = int(total_minutes / 60)
final_minutes = total_minutes % 60
final_hours = (hourHand + additional_hours) % 24

final_time = "{0}:{1}".format(final_hours,str(final_minutes).rjust(2,"0"))

print(final_time)
```

However you haven't specified really what your inputs and outputs are enough for me to know for sure.

Using rjust(2,"0") on the minute hand can keep you from having the if statements for if blah < 10 or whatever you were doing.

Everything else should be handled by division and modulus operators.